# Open Graph Built-in Like vs. Like Social Plug-in for mobile web apps

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a mobile app created using the javascript sdk, I would my user to be able to like posts, on the news feed. does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that prevents you from inserting multiple Like buttons on the same page.
Provided the first post leads to https://github.com/ and the second one to https://stackoverflow.com/ the Like buttons look like this:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://github.com/" data-width="450"></div>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://stackoverflow.com/" data-width="450"></div>
```

When the user clicks the like button, it appears on their Facebook page.

Note that the Likes should have links to pages that can be accessed by Facebook. Of course you can use your own pages.

More info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/